# Aggregating runs from multiple columns into a view with different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table:

[image]

I would like to create a view that aggregates the data with following rules:

1. If StatusDB==Completed and StatusXML==JobEnd then it is Success
2. If StatusDB==Failed and StatusXML==Failed then it is Fail
3. If (StatusDB!=Failed and StatusDB!=Completed) or (StatusXML!=Failed and StatusXML!=Completed) then it is Running (everything else than 1 and 2)

And the view will look like this from above:

[image]

I am not sure whether this is performed by a group by some how or what the best approach is. All input are welcome.

Comment: Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `case` expressions to do _conditional aggregation_.

Comment: Your rules are not clear at all.  Please explain them better.

Comment: I started trying that. Following as an example returns 4 rows. If I group by JobId only I cannot use StatusDB .. in the case: SELECT  
 CASE WHEN StatusToXML='JobEnd' and StatusToDB='Completed' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Completed 
FROM [dbo].[FileScanJobs]

group by StatusToXML, StatusToDB

Comment: To shorten the rules. If StatusXML is JobEnd and StatusDB is Completed then It is completed. If both are fail then it is Fail. Everything else is running.

Comment: @ThomasSegato Those rules give different result from what you posted. Question is veery unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set up sample data and written two queries, which might help you. They do not give exact result as needed, but rules are inconsistent, so I am positing this in order to give idea of what needs to be done:

```
select jobid,
       sum(case when statusDB = 'Completed' and statusXML = 'JobEnd' then 1 else 0 end) complete,
       sum(case when statusDB = 'Failed' and statusXML = 'Failed' then 1 else 0 end) fail,
       sum(case when (statusDB <> 'Completed' or statusXML <> 'JobEnd') and (statusXML <> 'Failed' or statusXML <> 'Failed') then 1 else 0 end) other
from tbl
group by jobid;

-- second query
select jobid,
       sum(case when statusDB = 'Completed' and statusXML = 'JobEnd' then 1 else 0 end) complete,
       sum(case when statusXML = 'Failed' then 1 else 0 end) fail,
       sum(case when (statusDB <> 'Completed' or statusXML <> 'JobEnd') and (statusXML <> 'Failed') then 1 else 0 end) other
from tbl
group by jobid;
```

[DB fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/06702/8)

Comment: Actually they are spot on. Just tested it out. What I missed here is that you can use columns that is not in the group by as long as they are in an agregate function like sum. Thanks appreciated!